# Return to caller function only after setState is complete

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I am new to reactjs. I want the function to return only after `setState` has occurred. My code looks something like this

```js
state={
  a: false,
  b: false
}

function1 = () =>{
  this.setState({a: true});
  //do something over here to wait until setState finishes
  //and then return to caller function
}

function2 = () =>{
    this.setState({b: true});
   //do something over here to wait until setState finishes
   //and then return to caller function
}


function3 = () =>{
  function1();
  function2();
  if(this.state.a && this.state.b === true){
      //perform something
  }
}
```

If I call `function3()` on click of a button, I am not getting the desired output as the state of a and b is not changing to true. How do I `//perform something` after the state has updated?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to execute both `function1` and `function2` and then perform the check. Since `setState` is asynchronous, you can use the callback option to resolve a promise on each function, and then on `function3` wait for both promises to resolve, and then perform your check.

Please see this example:

```
state={
  a: false,
  b: false
}

function1 = () => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    this.setState({a: true}, () => resolve());
    //do something over here to wait until setState finishes
    //and then return to caller function
  }
}

function2 = () => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    this.setState({b: true}, () => resolve());
    //do something over here to wait until setState finishes
    //and then return to caller function
  }
}


function3 = () =>{
  Promise.all([function1(), function2()]).then(() => {
    if(this.state.a && this.state.b === true){
      //perform something
    }
  });
}
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: As per my understanding, Promise.all() in function3 is asynchronous. So, whatever is below Promise.all() executes before "//perform something". Is there a way to '//perform something" and move to rest of the flow?

Comment: The rest of the flow is where the `//perform something` is (inside the callback). There is no reason to write any code below the `Promise.all`

Comment: But it returns to the calling function of function3 before it //perform something which is not desired.

Comment: `//perform something` is where you write the callback function that will be executed after `function1` AND `function2` are done

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I am understanding your issue but `setState()` takes a callback function that if called after that state has been updated so for your example, you can simplify it like this:

```js
state = {
  a: false,
  b: false
}

function1 = () => {
  this.setState({a: true}, this.function3);
}

function2 = () => {
    this.setState({b: true}, this.function3);
}


function3 = () => {
  if(this.state.a && this.state.b === true){
      //perform something
  }
}
```

Check out [this example](https://jsfiddle.net/fatfisz/vLv6k3xL/) on using a setState callback.

Answer (score 0):

Setting State in React is an Async operation and you have to handle is asynchronously, So if you wanted to do something that executes after setState has occurred, you have to do this inside the callback function.

```
 state={
  a: false,
  b: false
}

function1 = () =>{
  this.setState({a: true}, this.function3);
}

function2 = () =>{
    this.setState({b: true}, function3);
}


function3 = () =>{
  if(this.state.a && this.state.b === true){
      // Do what you want 
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`setState` callback function is what you needed here :

As per your code, I would suggest this

```
state={
  a: false,
  b: false
}

function1 = () =>{
    this.setState({a: true},() => {
        //when setState finishes
        this.checkState();
    });
}

function2 = () =>{
    this.setState({b: true},() => {
        //when setState finishes
        this.checkState();
    });
}


function3 = () =>{
    function1();
    function2();
}

checkState() {
    if(this.state.a && this.state.b === true){
        //perform something
    }
}
```